# Inconsistent comprehension syntax?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I just stumbled over what seems to be a flaw in the python syntax-- or else I'm missing something.

See this:

```
[x for x in range(30) if x % 2 == 0]
```

But this is a syntax error:

```
[x for x in range(30) if x % 2 == 0 else 5]
```

If you have an `else` clause, you have to write:

```
[x if x % 2 == 0 else 5 for x in range (30)]
```

But this is a syntax error:

```
[x if x %2 == 0 for x in range(30)]
```

What am I missing? Why is this so inconsistent?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are *mixing* syntax here. There are **two** different concepts at play here:

- List comprehension syntax. Here `if` acts as a filter; include a value in the iteration or not. There is no `else`, as that is the 'don't include' case already.
- A [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). This must always return a value, either the outcome of the 'true' or the 'false' expression.

Remember: list comprehensions *produce a sequence of values from a loop*. By  using `if` you can control how many elements from the input iterable are used for the output.

A *conditional expression* on the other hand, works like any other expression: an expression always produces a single result; the conditional expression lets you pick between two possible outcomes. But because it *must* produce a result you can’t write one without the `else` part.

Note that expressions can and are frequently *nested*. The conditional expression itself contains three sub-expressions:

```
expr1 if expr2 else expr3
# ^                   ^
# \ used when expr2   |
#   is true           |
#                     /
#   used when expr2 is
#   false
```

List comprehension also contain sub-expressions. The one at the start (before the `for <target> in <iterable>` part) is the sub-expression that is executed each iteration to produce the value in the output list. The iterator expression (after `in`) is another. The optional `if` filter takes an expression too. In any of these places you could use a conditional expression if you so choose. But, that doesn’t mean you can add an extra `else` to the list comprehension without the other parts of the conditional expression syntax.

Comment: Oh...so there is no way to do an `else` as part of the comprehension.

Comment: @Aerovistae: No, it is not part of the syntax, as *there is no point*.

Comment: Well if you wanted to insert blanks (or something) everywhere that something was omitted...

Comment: Then you are not omitting, you are replacing and the conditional expression works just fine.

Comment: @Aerovistae Using `if` at the end of the list comp syntax is what is telling the list comp whether or not to include it. `[foo for foo in bar if isinstance(foo,basestring)]` checks `isinstance(foo,basestring)` and if it's `False` immediately discards that foo. If you want to include `foo` regardless of whether or not its a `basestring`, but maybe do something to it if it isn't (`str(foo)`?), then don't put it in the filter at the end, instead assign it as a conditional expression. `[foo if isinstance(foo,basestring) else str(foo) for foo in bar]` now the list comp looks at ALL `foo`s in `bar`.

Comment: @Aerovistae in other words: `if` at the end filters values from being included. `if` at the beginning isn't really its own thing, you're just replacing `[(((foo))) for foo in bar]` with `[(((foo if conditional else baz))) for foo in bar]`. It's not part of the list comp syntax, it's just plugging a conditional statement into the value.

Answer (score 6):

> What am I missing?

The following is a *ternary operation* (aka "conditional expression" in python parlance)

```
x if some_boolean else y
```

This evaluates like it reads: if `some_boolean` is `True`, give me `x`, else give me y.

Do not confuse this with comprehension syntax:

```
(expression) for (iteration variable) in (iterable) [if (filter)]
```

A conditional expression can go into the (expression) part.  It doesn't have anything to do with the optional `if (filter)` part.

Comment: The conditional expression is *a* ternary operator, just as `or` is a *binary* operator. But to use 'ternary operator' as a name for the conditional expression is not correct; ternary just refers to the fact that it takes three operands, and as such ternary operators are a *class* of expressions, never a specific one. The fact that Python only has one such operator doesn't matter here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "ternary if" is likely more correct, but I find it needlessly pedantic to further qualify "ternary operator" in a language that only has one ternary operator.  I know it rubs some people the wrong way to say *the* ternary operator, but if there's only one... eh.  YMMV.

Comment: It is an operator, with 3 operands, so ternary operator is a fine term, but it is still a *class* or *type* designation, just like binary operator, and not a name. 'conditional expression' is the name used in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between the two is that the trailing `if` in the first one is part of the [list comprehension syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), while the `if-else` is the conditional operator, not any part of the list comprehension syntax - as it is an expression which is permitted in that part of a list comprehension.

The [syntax for the conditional operator](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is as follows:

```
x if condition1 else y
```

This returns the value of the expression that is evaluated, which is why it seems to "work" for your case, though it evaluates all of the time and returns always - which is the key difference between the two.

Meanwhile, for the list comprehension, it tests whether or not the condition applies, and **does *not* add that in the new list created** if the condition does not evaluate to true according to the [Truth Value Testing procedure](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), not `None` nor anything else.

Compare the following (taking an example from [PEP202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202)):

```
a = [i if i % 2 == 0 else None for i in range(20)]
b =  [i for i in range(20) if i % 2 == 0]
```

`a` would be

```
[0, None, 2, None, 4, None, 6, None, 8, None, 10, None, 12, None, 14, None, 16, None, 18, None]
```

while `b` would be

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

which isn't the same at all, as no matter what the result of it is, it will still add it in if there is no `if` part of the *list comprehension*.

Comment: So how can I do an if/else as part of the comprehension? Is that possible?

Comment: @Aerovistae: no, you can't use `elif` in a conditional operator.