# In python how does "if-else and for" in a dictionary comprehension work

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary-comprehension

I am confused with the following line of code:

```
data = {n.attributes['xid']: float(n.content) if n.content else np.nan for n in graph.by_tag('value') }
```

The dictionary comprehension consists of `if-else` and `for` loop. Can anyone explain me how the code works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does a translation help?

```
data = {}
for n in graph.by_tag('value'):
    if n.content:
        data[n.attributes['xid']] = float(n.content)
    else:
        data[n.attributes['xid']] = np.nan
```

Comment: The dictionay comprehension dates = {n.attributes['xid']: str(n.content) for n in dates.by_tag('value')}. Can I abbreviate the dict comprehension as follows :                                                                       dates ={}
         for n in dates.by_tag('value'):
            dates[n.attributes['xid']] =str(n.content)

Comment: Nearly, but you need to use a different variable name (you're overwriting `dates` in the first line).

Answer (score 2):

You are confused by the [`... if ... else ...` conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). It is not part of the loop, it is part of the expression generating the value for each key-value pair.

A dictionary comprehension consists of at least one loop, with optionally more loops and `if` filters on the right-hand side, and *two* expressions on the left. One expression to produce a key, and another to produce a value. Together the two expressions make a key-value pair for the resulting dictionary:

```
{key_expression: value_expression for target in iterable}
```

The conditional expression simply produces a value based on a test. Either the test evaluates to true and one value is picked, or the value is false and the other is picked:

```
true_expression if test else false_expression
```

Only the expression picked is evaluated; if `test` ends up as false, the `false_expression` is executed and the result is returned, the `true_expression` is ignored entirely.

Thus, the dictionary comprehension you are looking at is the equivalent of:

```
data = {}
for n in graph.by_tag('value'):
    key = n.attributes['xid']
    value = float(n.content) if n.content else np.nan
    data[key] = value
```

So the `value` is either set to `float(n.content)`, or to `np.nan`, depending on the value of `n.content` (truethy or not).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Is there any tutorial on list and dict comphrehensions. Please often i get struck with these comphreshions. I am more into datascience.

Comment: @user3796494: the Python tutorial [covers list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions); once you have list comprehensions under your belt, generator expressions and set and dict comprehensions are no different.

Comment: @MartijinPieters - Whats is difference between these two list comphrenhensions:
data = {n.attributes['xid']: float(n.content) if n.content else np.nan for n in graph.by_tag('value') }

data = {n.attributes['xid']: float(n.content) for n in graph.by_tag('value') if n.content else np.nan }

Comment: @user3796494: the second is invalid syntax. Without the `else` part there you are *filtering*; removing items from consideration, so you end up with fewer items in the dictionary. The former takes *all* items and varies what value is stored in an expression.

Comment: @MartijinPieters - Bascially what is the difference between these two syntax ?? . Some_variable = [y for(condition) if (condition)] and some_variable = [y if(condition) for (condition)]. List comprehensions are some what confusing.

Comment: @user3796494: see [Inconsistent comprehension syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20025305) You are getting confused by the conditional expression (not part of the list/set/dict comprehension syntax) and the comprehension syntax.

Comment: @user3796494: the two things are *separate* concepts. You can use a conditional expression anywhere.

Comment: @MartijinPieters - so how can we write the following as a list. if (some condition): /n for (some condition): "create a list".

Comment: @user3796494: sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to do there. Perhaps make that a separate question on Stack Overflow?