# Dictionary comphrehension

Tags: python, ipython

This is the complete code for which I am getting the error:

```
import requests
from pattern import web 
url = "http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1044.xml"
website_html = requests.get(url).text

def rcp_poll_data(xml):
    dom = web.Element(xml)

    dates = dom.by_tag('series')[0]    
    dates = {n.attributes['xid']: str(n.content) for n in dates.by_tag('value')}
```

My question:

```
dates = {n.attributes['xid']: str(n.content) for n in dates.by_tag('value')}
```

Does the below mentioned python code, exactly replicate the above dictionary comprehension:

```
dates = dom.by_tag('series')[0]
dates = {}  
for n in dates.by_tag('value'):
          dates[n.attributes['xid']] =str(n.content)
```

Comment: Can you just run it and see?

Comment: Yes. What is your actual question or problem? Are you seeing different results from the comprehension?

Comment: yes! but what is your Question

Comment: This is the first time I can link to a duplicate question in a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25989127/20670 :)

Comment: No, it does not, since you overwrite the variable `dates`. The second snippet will fail with `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'by_tag'`

Comment: When I run this code I get the following error "List index out of range"

Comment: Then what is the best way to replicate the dic comprehension

Comment: You must be running somewhat different code, I can't see any lists there. Please provide [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @bereal then pls suggest me a better way to replicate the dict comprehension.

Comment: @MJP why do you need something other than dict comprehension? Anyways, to my understanding the second snippet should work once you rename the destination dict.

Comment: @bereal:  i was curious about the code.So wanted to know how it works. But I am still confused. Can you type the replicated version in the comment.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same, with a minor difference that's causing you the problem.

In both cases you're iterating over `dates.by_tag('value')`. In the first case, first the dictionary is created, and then assigned to the variable `dates`. In the second case, you're assigning a `{}` to `dates` before you even begin - and then you can't access `dates.by_tag('value')` anymore. If you do this, it will work exactly the same:

```
tmp_d={}
for n in dates.by_tag('value'):
          tmp_d[n.attributes['xid']] =str(n.content)
dates = tmp_d
```

**Answer to your update**: Even after your update, my answer still holds.

```
dates = dom.by_tag('series')[0]
dates = {}
```

These two lines first assign one thing to dates, and then another.

If you're getting a list index out of range error it's because `dom.by_tag('series')` returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippet will not work because you overwrite the variable `dates`, so that the input structure is no longer available. This should fix it:

```
result = {}
for n in dates.by_tag('value'):
    result[n.attributes['xid']] = str(n.content)
```

If you want something shorter that does not use dict comprehension and therefore 2.6-friendly, you can use a dict constructor that accepts a collection of pairs `(key, value)`.

```
result = dict((n.attributes['xid'], str(n.content)) for n in dates.by_tag('value'))
```

Comment: def any_function(xml):
    dom = web.Element(xml)
    dates = dom.by_tag('series')[0]
    manu ={}
    for n in dates.by_tag('value'):
            manu[n.attributes['xid']] =str(n.content)
print any_function(url) # url = "http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1044.xml"

Comment: This is was my code for which i got the error as 
"IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @MJP Please consider updating your question with this code and the full stacktrace.

Comment: @MJP that little `[0]` can make a lot of difference.

Comment: so what is the solution, I have updated the question.

Comment: This code does not reproduce the `IndexError`. As for the original question on how to rewrite the comprehension, see the answer above.