# How to "else" in a list comprehension when the condition is non-boolean?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, if-statement, list-comprehension

Given a list e.g.

```
a = ["No", 1, "No"]
```

I want to convert this to a new list (or actually just re-assign the list) such that each "No" gets converted to a 0 e.g.

```
[0,1,0]
```

If I try the following list comprehension:

```
[0 for i in a if i =="No"]
```

This obviously results in a list that omits every element that is not "No"

```
[0,0]
```

If I follow the lead given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2951722/1389110) and try:

```
[0 if "No" else i for i in a]
```

This gives me:

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

And I guess this is because "No" equates to `True`.

What am I misunderstanding about the usage of if/else in a list comprehension?

Comment: Also related: [Inconsistent comprehension syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20025280)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a boolean expression by using `==` operator

```
>>> a = ["No", 1, "No"]
>>> [0 if i == "No" else i for i in a]
[0, 1, 0]
```

Or another way is

```
>>> [[0, i][i != "No"] for i in a]
[0, 1, 0]
```

This works because `i != "No"` returns a boolean value which can be then interpreted as `1` for True and `0` for false. This then is used to access that particular element from the list `[0, i]`

Comment: or  `[int(i != "No") for i in a]` or  `[[1,0 ][i == "No"] for i in a]` ;)

Comment: Hehe. Nice trick @Padraic. But the OP wants to print that item in the original list, so can't use it here. :(

Comment: I guess  `[[0, i][i != "No"] for i in a]` should do the trick